# Field value of integer doesn't get submitted (Simple form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

In my application a user has to fill in their house number. This is done through the simple_form gem but everytime I click submit it says house number can't be blank. This means the field value doesn't get submitted. How come?

**Schema.rb**

```
t.integer "house_number"
```

**Simpleform**

```
<%= f.input :house_number %>
```

**Model**

```
validates :house_number, presence: true, numericality: :integer, allow_blank: false
```

**EDIT**

I removed allow_blank because it might seem redundant. It still doesn't work though. The request log is posted below.

```
Started POST "/postcodes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-04 16:28:14 +0100
Processing by PostcodesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: 
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"0POd0L1b81uY1nSgW6b5NHLdG5KRkA0bUB4p7wwJhxk=", 
"postcode"=>  {"zipcode"=>"1234aa", "house_number"=>"2", "street_name"=>"", "city"=>""},   "commit"=>"Submit"}
Unpermitted parameters: house_number
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered postcodes/_form.html.erb (18.0ms)
  Rendered postcodes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35ms (Views: 28.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: Please post the log of the request including the `params` hash

Comment: just wanted to know as of curiousity, if presence is already true, then what is the purpose of allow_blank: false

Comment: davidb, I added the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the log I see I forgot the added house_number to the strong params!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
validates :house_number, presence: true, numericality: :integer
```